# MySQL - condition on the joined row from from right table

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have two tables:

```
mysql> select * from orders;
+------+---------------------+------------+---------+
| id   | created_at          | foreign_id | data    |
+------+---------------------+------------+---------+
|    1 | 2010-10-10 10:10:10 |          3 | order 1 |
|    4 | 2010-10-10 00:00:00 |          6 | order 4 |
|    5 | 2010-10-10 00:00:00 |          7 | order 5 |
+------+---------------------+------------+---------+

mysql> select * from activities;
+------+---------------------+------------+------+
| id   | created_at          | foreign_id | verb |
+------+---------------------+------------+------+
|    1 | 2010-10-10 10:10:10 |          3 | get  |
|    2 | 2010-10-10 10:10:15 |          3 | set  |
|    3 | 2010-10-10 10:10:20 |          3 | put  |
|    4 | 2010-10-10 00:00:00 |          6 | get  |
|    5 | 2010-10-11 00:00:00 |          6 | set  |
|    6 | 2010-10-12 00:00:00 |          6 | put  |
+------+---------------------+------------+------+
```

Now I need to join `activities` with `orders` on `foreign_id` column: select only one activity (if exists) for every order such that `ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, orders.created_at, activities.created_at))` is minimal. E.g. the order and the activity were created approximately at the same time.

```
+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------+------+---------------------+
| order_id | data    | order_created_at    | activity_id | verb | activity_created_at |
+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------+------+---------------------+
|        1 | order 1 | 2010-10-10 10:10:10 |           1 | get  | 2010-10-10 10:10:10 |
|        4 | order 4 | 2010-10-10 00:00:00 |           4 | get  | 2010-10-10 00:00:00 |
|        5 | order 5 | 2010-10-10 00:00:00 |        NULL | NULL | NULL                |
+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------+------+---------------------+
```

The following query produces set of rows that includes the desired rows. If `GROUP BY` statement is included then it's not possible to control which row from `activities` is joined.

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id
     , o.data AS data
     , o.created_at AS order_created_at
     , a.id AS activity_id
     , a.verb AS verb
     , a.created_at AS activity_created_at 
FROM orders AS o 
LEFT JOIN activities AS a ON a.foreign_id = o.foreign_id;
```

Is it possible to write such a query? Ideally I'd like to avoid using group by because this section is a part of larger reporting querty.

Comment: what do you want to do with this line: `ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, orders.created_at, activities.created_at))`?

Comment: I want to minimize this value. E.g. if the order has been created at 11:00, and there are three activities (1, 09:00), (2, 10:00), (3, 11:00), (3, 12:00) I want the third activity. That line will return number of seconds between creations or the order and the activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both tables reference some mysterious foreign key there's potential for errors with the query below, but it may give you a principle which you can adapt for your purposes...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS orders;

CREATE TABLE orders
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,created_at DATETIME NOT NULL
,foreign_id INT NOT NULL
,data    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
(1 ,'2010-10-10 10:10:10',3 ,'order 1'),
(4 ,'2010-10-10 00:00:00',6 ,'order 4'),
(5 ,'2010-10-10 00:00:00',7 ,'order 5');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS activities;

CREATE TABLE activities
(id   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,created_at          DATETIME NOT NULL
,foreign_id INT NOT NULL
,verb VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO activities VALUES
(1,'2010-10-10 10:10:10',3,'get'),
(2,'2010-10-10 10:10:15',3,'set'),
(3,'2010-10-10 10:10:20',3,'put'),
(4,'2010-10-10 00:00:00',6,'get'),
(5,'2010-10-11 00:00:00',6,'set'),
(6,'2010-10-12 00:00:00',6,'put');

SELECT o.id order_id
     , o.data
     , o.created_at order_created_at    
     , a.id activity_id 
     , a.verb 
     , a.created_at activity_created_at 
  FROM activities a 
  JOIN orders o 
    ON o.foreign_id = a.foreign_id 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT a.foreign_id
            , MIN(ABS(TIMEDIFF(a.created_at,o.created_at))) x 
         FROM activities a 
         JOIN orders o 
           ON o.foreign_id = a.foreign_id 
        GROUP 
           BY a.foreign_id
     ) m 
    ON m.foreign_id = a.foreign_id
   AND m.x = ABS(TIMEDIFF(a.created_at,o.created_at))
 UNION DISTINCT
SELECT o.id 
     , o.data
     , o.created_at
     , a.id
     , a.verb
     , a.created_at
  FROM orders o
  LEFT
  JOIN activities a
    ON a.foreign_id = o.foreign_id 
 WHERE a.foreign_id IS NULL;
;

+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------+------+---------------------+
| order_id | data    | order_created_at    | activity_id | verb | activity_created_at |
+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------+------+---------------------+
|        1 | order 1 | 2010-10-10 10:10:10 |           1 | get  | 2010-10-10 10:10:10 |
|        4 | order 4 | 2010-10-10 00:00:00 |           4 | get  | 2010-10-10 00:00:00 |
|        5 | order 5 | 2010-10-10 00:00:00 |        NULL | NULL | NULL                |
+----------+---------+---------------------+-------------+------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. I ended up modifying your query a little bit: SELECT o.id, o.data, a.verb, m.x
    `FROM orders o
 LEFT JOIN ( 
  SELECT o2.id o_id
       , a2.id a_id
       , MIN(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, a2.created_at, o2.created_at))) x
  FROM orders o2 
  JOIN activities a2 
   ON o2.foreign_id = a2.foreign_id
  GROUP 
   BY o2.foreign_id
 ) m 
  ON m.o_id = o.id
 LEFT JOIN activities a
  ON m.a_id = a.id`

Comment: Ops, I didn't notice your edit. My modified query seems to achieve the same results, and it's somewhat simpler than yours.

Comment: Given that o2.foreign_id = a2.foreign, I don't see the point of selecting a2.id. I don't think our queries are logically identical, so they will produce different results on larger data sets. But only you can say which is correct. Also, both will struggle with large time differences. It may be better to convert to seconds, do the math, and then convert back. In terms of performance, I have a sneaky suspicion that yours is actually faster than mine - but I'm not sure.